# how to create multi step custom form back button in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-8

i make custom form with 2 steps, i want if user click on back button on step 2 form redirect to step 1 and show the data which the user has entered at the beginning. and this is my code

```
function example_form($form, &$form_state) {

  if (!empty($form_state['step_num'])) {
    return example_step_two($form, $form_state);
  }

  $form_state['step_num'] = 1;

  $form['title'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Title'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  $form['next'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Next',
    '#submit' => array('example_form_submit'),
  );

  return $form;
}
```

and this is my submit function

```
function orders_order_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  $form_state['page_values']['1'] = $form_state['values'];

  if (!empty($form_state['page_values'][2])) {
    $form_state['values'] = $form_state['page_values'][2];
  }

  $form_state['step_number'] = 2;
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```

and this is step two of my form

```
function example_form_step_two($form, &$form_state){

  $form['title2'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Title2'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  $form['back'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Back'),
    '#submit' => array('example_form_step_two_back'),
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit',
    '#submit' => array('example_form_step_two_submit'),
  );

  return $form;
}
```

and this is the problem function for back button

```
function example_form_step_two_back($form, &$form_state){

  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to test if `'step_num'` is 2 in `example_form()`, not if it's not empty:

```
if ($form_state['step_num'] == 2) {
    return example_step_two($form, $form_state);
}
```

Then in `example_form_step_two_back()`, you need to add:

```
$form_state['step_num'] = 1;
```

To display the previously user-entered value of `'title'`, you have to add a `'#default_value'` element to it which is set if that value exists.